# g++ 9.2.1 on modern Intel: any way at all to get CMPXCHG16B instructions generated from C++11 atomic<> or C11 atomic_compare_exchange_strong

Tags: c++11, atomic, c11

I simply want an instruction, not a library call, for speed when I'm using atomic<> with 16-byte types.
Duh: the main reason anyone uses atomic<> with 16-byte types is surely for speed!

The man page is teasing me:

> -mcx16
>
> This option enables GCC to generate "CMPXCHG16B" instructions in 64-bit code to implement compare-and-exchange operations on 16-byte aligned 128-bit objects.  This is useful for atomic updates of data structures exceeding one machine word in size.  The compiler uses this instruction to implement __sync Builtins.  **However, for __atomic Builtins operating on 128-bit integers, a library call is always used.**

I'd even welcome an assembly version, though for odd reasons I'm using C11, not C++11.  (A C++11 solution would certainly be welcome enough though!)

This is my compiler:

```
>  g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,ada,go,d,lto --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-gcc-major-version-only --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --with-isl --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-cet --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1) (GCC)
```

Comment: I have no current experience with that particular compiler version, but my impression in times was that `-march=native` was enough to generate such instructions when that was possible. Has that changed?

Comment: -march=native doesn't suffice to make the code self-standing on this release of GCC... still needs -latomic ...